# Rendering Problems in activity main

Tags: android-studio

I'm tired of searching.
Help me please

**what is this `error`:**

`Renderin`g Problems
 The following `classes` could not be found:

```
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.  Couldn't resolve resource @color/white (2 similar errors not shown) Failed to convert @color/white into a drawable (Details)
```

Comment: post your color.xml and string xml code

Comment: hi  sasikumar  this is color.xml cod:?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>        and this is string xml code: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>

Comment: you done mistake  in @color/white .so check your drawable.is any xml in there?

Comment: In the drawble nothing.   this is right?     <color name="color/white"></color>

Answer (score 1):

you done mistake in @color/white.color should be define in following format.

res/values/colors.xml

```
 <resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 </resources>
```

you can use color in your Activity or fragment

```
    android:textColor="@color/white"
     or 
    android:background="@color/white"
```